# Running ant from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, ftp

I am trying to deploy my zip file from local machine to remote machine, i am using jenkins with ant. the problem is build gets success but 0 files has been sent to remote machine using ftp.

my build.xml file as below

```
<project name="test" default="test">

<target name="test">
<zip destfile="htmlfiles.zip">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.php"/>
    </fileset>
</zip>

<ftp server="192.168.0.66"
   userid="admin"
   password="admin">
<fileset dir="C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\ftp">
<include name="*"/>
</fileset>
</ftp>
</target>
</project>
```

and following my result of jenkins

```
  test:
  [zip] Building zip: C:\Users\ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\test\htmlfiles.zip
  [ftp] sending files
  [ftp] 0 files sent

  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
  Total time: 0 seconds
  Finished: SUCCESS
```

anyone help me out that why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if its works for you.

```
<project name="test" default="test">

<target name="test">
<property name="distdir" value="C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\ftp"/>
<zip destfile="${distdir}/htmlfiles.zip">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.php"/>
    </fileset>
</zip>

<ftp server="192.168.0.66"
   userid="admin"
   password="admin">
<fileset dir="C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\ftp">
<include name="*"/>
</fileset>
</ftp>
</target>
</project>
```

As i can see from logs that your .zip file is created at `C:\Users\ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\test\htmlfiles.zip` but in `ftp` tag you have specified the location `"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\ftp"`. `fileset` in ftp folder doesn't specify the destination directory. The file will be put in default folder for ftp user(here which is `admin`)

Comment: Actually I am new with xml files

Comment: I tried but getting an error like 'BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\test\build.xml:14: could not put file: 550-The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
 Win32 error:   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
 Error details: File system returned an error.
550 End'

Comment: this is working but it is applicable when I am working on local server , but to deploy it on my production server i need to use ftp.

Comment: Please paste the log after you made the changes i suggested